# Finding an element in Webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find test1 here but I cannot. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
<button class="btn toggle-tab active" data-filter="test1">test1</button>
<button class="btn toggle-tab" data-filter="test2">test2</button>
<button class="btn toggle-tab" data-filter="test3">test3</button>
<button class="btn toggle-tab" data-filter="test4">test4</button
```

what I have tried is-

```
.//*[text()='test1']

.//title[text()='test1']

.//data-filter[text()="test1"]
```

Comment: is the button inside another frame?

Comment: When you say it's not found, is there an exception message? You should spend some time reading up on XPaths and how they are formed. You are using them incorrectly but it's beyond the scope of a comment to explain everything here.

Comment: Yes, the button is inside a iframe.  how do I navigate to the the right node?

Answer (score 1):

```
"//button[contains(.,'test1')]"
```

There are other ways, but I prefer contains over equal (=) and in contains, I prefer "." over "text()"

You're effectively searching for the first tagname "button" which contains the text 'test1'

This question is more XPath-related, so you may want to include the xpath tag in your future posts that refer to them.

Comment: Show me your code, at least the line performing the retrieval, please.

Answer (score 0):

**Xpath to find linktext is -**
//htmltag[text()='linktext']

**Here in your case, the xpath will be**-
//button[text()='test1']

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using XPath to locate the element, try using CSS selectors.
The CSS selector for test1 would be **button[class$='active']**.
It is always better to use id, CSS selector or class name when locating elements.xpath is generally preferred in the worst case scenario, and fortunately, I have encountered just a few cases.